# What is different between writeBinaryMessage() and write() of Vert.x WebSocket?

Tags: java, websocket, vert.x

I'm working on a server project using Vert.x and its `ServerWebSocket` class.

Currently, my project uses the `Pump#pump()` and `ServerWebSocket#write()` methods to send large binary data to clients and it works well. But I found that `ServerWebSocket` has another method to send binary data, `writeBinaryMessage()`.

The manual says:

> `writeBinaryMessage()` : This data might be written as multiple frames if it exceeds the maximum WebSocket frame size

But I think that `ServerWebSocket#write()` also sends data as multiple parts by pumping the stream.

What is the difference between `writeBinaryMessage()` and `write()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*writeBinaryMessage()*:

- Writes a (potentially large) piece of binary data to the connection. This data might be written as multiple frames if it exceeds the maximum WebSocket frame size.

*write()*

- Write some data to the stream. The data is put on an internal write queue, and the write actually happens asynchronously. To avoid running out of memory by putting too much on the write queue, check the WriteStream.writeQueueFull() method before writing. This is done automatically if using a Pump.

Both returns the same type of data and takes Buffer type of parameter.

Only the difference is that the both functions handle the data internally different.

If you want to write a big binary data, then you should use *writeBinaryMessage(Buffer data)* and if you send alot small messages dynamically then you should use async function *write(Buffer data)*

See:

- [write(Buffer data)](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/rxjava/core/http/WebSocketBase.html#write-io.vertx.rxjava.core.buffer.Buffer-)
- [writeBinaryMessage(Buffer data)](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/rxjava/core/http/WebSocketBase.html#writeBinaryMessage-io.vertx.rxjava.core.buffer.Buffer-)